# Is @staticmethod proliferation a code smell?

Tags: python, code-quality, code-smell, static-methods

Consider a Python class with a number of `@staticmethod` methods and few instance methods. The static methods don't accept an instance of the defining class as parameters.

- Do you think that all these static methods don't belong to the class and should be factored out?
- If yes, which approach would you take to clean up such code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like a module masquerading as a class (which is common to see in a language like Java where there are no methods outside of classes, so the only way to make something that looks like a module is to make a static only class).  If the static methods are doing something that's actually related to the class as a whole, such as managing a pool of them, generating them (factories) or something along those lines then yes, they might be legitimate static methods.  Otherwise, they probably should just be module level methods.

Comment: Even if they do work related to the class (e.g. providing a helper to instanciate the object in a different way, like `SomeDataContainer.from_file`), the only reason not to make it a `classmethod` instead is if the class is not expected to ever be subclassed.